# Extract elements between first and last occurrence of characters

Tags: java

I have a json string which is part of another string -

```
This is a json {"name":"jim","age":12,"contactDetails": {"phone":"xxxxx"}} json ended
```

In this example , I would like to extract the string starting from first { and ending at last }.

Thanks for the answers. Below code works as suggested -

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String jsonData = "This is a json {\"name\":\"jim\",\"age\":12,\"contactDetails\": {\"phone\":\"xxxxx\"}} json ended";
        System.out.println(jsonData.substring(jsonData.indexOf("{"), jsonData.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));

    }


}
```

Comment: You can use `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` and then use these two indexes in `substring`

Comment: Regex would also probably work here, but indexOf and lastIndexOf would probably be the simplest path to take

Comment: So if you have the code answer your own question and mark it as accepted.  It keeps the unanswered list neat since the question shows up as answered. You can accept your own answer as well.

Comment: I thought Thilo or Legman can post the answer as  I just followed their suggestion. But I will answer to keep it clean :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Test {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String jsonData = "This is a json {\"name\":\"jim\",\"age\":12,\"contactDetails\": {\"phone\":\"xxxxx\"}} json ended";
        System.out.println(jsonData.substring(jsonData.indexOf("{"), jsonData.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program above may not work when you have given a nested JSON, so for that purpose you should take the first index of { and the last index of }, so you should be using the functions such as Indexof and lastIndexof, because these will give you the required indexes and then you can easily get a substring out of it... Hopefully I solved your query, do ask if you need more clarification... Happy to help..

Comment: Thanks Chandan , can you please help clarify? I had used indexOf and lastIndexOf. Also the example I used seems to have nested json. A code example would help. Thank you!

Comment: You yourself have provided a code below, I think that you have understood the concept. So, still you need a code snippet or it's fine?

Comment: sorry , I thought you mentioned that the code that I had provided would not work for nested json. If you don't think there are any issues with it , I'm good. Thanks for reviewing.